# Renci.sshnet not reading secret private key file from Azure Key Vault properly

Tags: azure, ssh, sftp, azure-keyvault

I have a key file that I am using with Renci.ssh to do sftp with.   However,  if I copy and paste this file into an Azure Secret, When I run the same code and try to read from the azure key vault I get "invalid key file"

Here is the code:

I have stored this file locally and read from this file and it works.  I have also cut and paste the key straight into my code and this also works.

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(config["SecretPrivateKey"])
             .ConfigureAwait(false);
var result = secret.Value;

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

PrivateKeyFile keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(stream, "Password");
```

Invalid key file

Comment: So what value do you get in `result`?

Comment: I figured it out.  I used the cli to add the key and it worked :  az keyvault secret set

Comment: yeah, but that's not code.    im having the same issue with my Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I used the cli to add the key and it worked : az keyvault secret set